# Terminal freezes with beach ball on High Sierra

Tags: terminal, high-sierra

My terminal frequently freeze with a spinning beach ball of doom. I've tested using both iTerm2 and the default Terminal, and it happens with both. And it doesn't seem to matter what I'm doing. I've had it freeze while nothing is running in any terminal, as well as while running a myriad of different programs (npm, webpack, gulp etc.).

When the terminals freeze, I'm able to force quit the app, but unable to start it again. And if one freeze, it seems to affect the other (if iTerm2 freeze and I force quit the app, I'm still unable to open Terminal). In order to use a terminal again I'm forced to reboot the machine.

While rebooting (after a terminal freeze) the machine also always hangs after closing all apps. I'm still able to move the cursor around on a black background, but that's it. The machine hangs there until I short circuit by holding down the power button.

**What I've tried**

I've tried resetting NVRAM and SMC to no avail.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out one question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: Are only the terminal applications frozen in these situations or do other applications show the same issue then? What does show up in Activity Monitor then? And (in reference to the other question you had) is the terminal problem occurring both with the external display connected *and* disconnected?

Comment: Only the terminals freeze, other apps work (seemingly) fine. But as I noted, the subsequent reboot also hangs. Unsure what Activity Monitor says. I've tried combing through the Console for errors, but I'm unable to decipher those logs (sidenote: I'm seeing a bunch of "Month 13 is out of bounds" warnings). And yes, the terminals freeze regardless of the extra monitor.

Comment: any luck on this?  happening to me now (on regular sierra, not high sierra).  it happened after updating docker (which ive since removed).  or maybe it was because i had a homebrew update script in `bash_profile`?  i've deleted bash profile and terminal's plist but it still happens.  as soon as i hit tab or something to make it access the filesystem, it beachballs and im stuck.

Comment: @oooyaya No solution yet, but after installing all the latest OS updates, the frequency of freezes has significantly reduced. I'm tempted to suspect this is at least partly a hardware issue.

Comment: I have the same issue! For me, Activity Monitor also freezes and doesn't display anything. I'm pretty sure it started when I installed docker-machine...

Comment: Actually, it could also be related to htop: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682

Comment: That's very interesting @Mark, and I am indeed running htop. Gonna try not running it for a while and see if the problem goes away. Thank you very much for the link, seems like the others describe my experience exactly!

Comment: Happy to report back that htop was indeed the culprit. No freezes since I stopped running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely being hit by a macOS 10.13.2 kernel bug, described [here](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/01/28/mac-freeze/), and exposed pretty regularly by htop, described [here](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/682).

Supposedly, macOS 10.13.4 beta has a kernel fix, and version 2.10.0 of htop was released to work around this bug.